# Simulation in R to check graphically that marginal distributions are correct

Tags: r, conditional-probability, simulation, marginal-distribution

The distribution on $R^2$ with joint density $h$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure is:
$$h(x,y)=\frac{3}{2}y 1_{A}(x,y), \ \  A=\{(x,y) \in R^2|0<y, x^2+y^2<1\}.$$
Then I have found the marginal density $f_X(x)=\frac{3}{4}(1-x^2)$

And therefore we get that the conditional distribution of Y given X is:
$$f(Y|X)=\frac{h(x,y)}{F_X(x)}=-\frac{2y}{x^2-1}$$

Now I have to use these results to simulate outcomes from the distribution of
$(X, Y)$, and check graphically that the marginal distributions are correct. I want to do that in R. But I'm not sure how to do that. I think I have to draw random outcomes $y_i$ from the marginal distribution of $X$. Then for each $x_i$, I think I have to draw an outcome from $P_{x_i}$ (the conditional distribution
of Y given X). But how can I do that simulation? I think simulation from a continuous distribution with CDF $F$ can be generated as $F^{-1}(U)$ where $U$ is uniform on $(0,1).$ Is that a correct understanding? Can anyone help me how to do that simulation in R?

Comment: Why aren't warning bells going off in your head when you write an expression for a marginal density with a negative sign in front of the formula?  Also, your marginal density expression and conditional density expression is incorrect in that neither has a $\mathbb 1_B(x)$ descriptor attached to it.

Comment: OK, so the conditional density can't be right. But that was not part of the problem as stated, which still makes sense.

Comment: @Dilip Although the negative sign is a flag, your next reaction should be to notice that the denominator is negative, too--there is no problem.

Comment: @whuber I _did_ notice the switching of sign in the denominator, but my point is that $-\frac{2y}{x^2-1}$ is _not_ a proper expression for the conditional density any more than $\frac 34(1-x^2)$ is a proper expression for the density of $X$, They need _restrictions_ on the values that $x$ and $y$ can take on to make them valid densities, and anyone who glibly talks of Lebesgue measure should be cognizant of this.

Comment: @Dilip Fair enough: that point was covered in the second part of your first comment.  The issue with the negative sign still looks like a red herring, that's all.

Answer (score 6):

Your value for the CDF of $X$ is incorrect, but perhaps this is just bad notation on your part.  What you have written is in fact the PDF of $X$.

Simulate $U_1$, a standard uniform random variable.  Plug this value into the inverse CDF $F^{-1}_X(U_1)$ of the marginal density of $X$.  (This inverse may not be tractable, although it exists, and the Acceptance-Rejection Algorithm may be better [Try Uniform(-1,1)]).  Save this value.  Next simulate another standard uniform random variable ($U_2$).  Plug this value and the saved $X$ value into the inverse CDF $F^{-1}_{Y|X} (U_2)$.  Now you have a random sample from the joint distribution $(X,Y)$.  Repeat however many times.

To do this in R, you just have to code the functions and use the ${\tt runif}$ function.

Comment: No need to use inverse CDF's (quantile functions) explicitly in R, because `rbeta` with appropriate parameters generates random samples from the a beta distribution.

Comment: Good comment, but it is better that OP understands the process in general

Comment: @user277126 Thank you, it makes a bit sense and I think that this is what I exactly what I have to do. But I think that I can only solve it numerically, while the marginal distribution of X because the quantile function cannot be found
explicitly but must be solved numerically by using uniroot. But I think it possible to do it the other way around by using the conditional distribution
of X given Y, and use it together with the marginal distribution for Y. Can you help me with the code, if I find and write the marginal density for Y and the conditional distribution
of X given Y?

Comment: Yes, you can work with either conditional distribution

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a way of checking your mathematical analysis by means of a simulation *that relies as little as possible on that analysis.*  Otherwise--if you base the code on your calculations--the code will give results that are only as correct as the calculations themselves.  It wouldn't be much of a check at all.

**In this instance, rejection sampling is an attractive prospect** because the problem formulation makes this method very simple to implement and it's not too inefficient.  (As we will see, only about two-thirds of the points will be rejected.)  The idea is that projecting the *uniform* distribution of points $(x,y,z)$ where $0 \le z \le h(x,y)$ onto the $(x,y)$ plane (obviously) produces the given distribution, because the density of such points per unit area is--by construction--proportional to the range of possible $z$ values, $h(x,y)-0 = h(x,y).$

**The only preliminary analysis needed** is to note that the definition of the region $\mathcal A$ implies $-1\le x \le 1$ and $0\le y\le 1.$  Moreover, because $0\le y\le 1,$ it is obvious that $h(x,y) \le 3/2.$  Thus, the set of points $\mathcal E$ in question is wholly contained within the box $[-1,1]\times [0,1]\times [0,3/2]\subset\mathbb{R}^3.$ (It is a portion of a vertical cylinder.)

**Rejection sampling** generates uniformly random points within the box and just throws out any such points not in $\mathcal E.$

Here is the immediate solution in `R`:

```R
n <- 1e4
X <- data.frame(x = runif(n, -1, 1), y = runif(n, 0, 1), z = runif(n, 0, 3/2))
i <- with(X, 0 < y & x^2 + y^2 < 1 & z <= (3/2)*y) # Indexes of points to keep
X <- X[i, ]
```

The first line specifies how many points, `n`, to generate within the box.  The second line generates those points, component by component, as rows of a data frame.  The third line identifies which points to keep, *simply by applying the formula for $h.$ The fourth line retains just those points in the data.frame object `X`.  ```

In this case, 3352 points of the original 10000 were retained, which is large enough to give precise indications of all three distributions.  (You can reproduce this simulation by preceding it with `set.seed(17)`.)

**You will want to examine the results.**  The realization of $(x,y)$ can be shown with its scatterplot (left panel) while their marginal distributions can be displayed with histograms (middle and right panels).  The basic `R` commands are

```R
with(X, {plot(x,y); hist(x, freq=FALSE); hist(y, freq=FALSE)})
```

[image: Figure]

Because you are using this to check your density calculations, you can do so by superimposing graphs of the computed marginal densities on the histograms.  I have used your expression $f_x(x) = (3/4)(1-x^2)$ in the second panel to check the marginal density of $x.$  (You can add another call to `curve` to superimpose your computed expression for $f_y$ on the histogram for $y$ in the right panel.)  The match is good: the slight deviations between the (middle) histogram and the graph can be attributed to random variation in the simulation.  (Check this with a chi-squared test if you like.)

#### Appendix 1

**You can use such results to approximate the marginal distributions, too.**  Given a value of $x,$ choose all $y$ values from points $(x^\prime,y)$ where $x^\prime$ is close to $x.$  The result is a mixture of conditional distributions in a narrow strip.  Except near the extremes ($x$ near $\pm 1$ or $y$ near $1$) where the conditional distributions change rapidly, these mixtures will be reasonably close and will serve as an excellent check.

For instance, **here are plots of the conditional $y$ distribution for four selected values of $x.$**  They are based on the same simulation, but this time with a million points drawn (before rejection).

[image: Figure 2]

On these I have superimposed the graphs of $f_{y\mid x}(y) = -y/(x^2-1)I_{[0\le y\le \sqrt{1-x^2}]}(y).$  They check out nicely.

**In the same manner, the conditional distributions of $x$ given $y$ can be approximated and plotted:**

[image: Figure 3]

Because you have not supplied a formula for these densities, I haven't graphed anything on them for comparison.  But the pattern is suggestive, isn't it?  One would guess these are *uniform* distributions on an interval that shrinks as $y$ grows large.  Referring to the left panel in the first figure will show you exactly how it shrinks.

#### Appendix 2

To create the first figure, the basic `R` plotting commands were modified to decorate the plots, overplot the graph of $f_x,$ and make them fit in a single graphic:

```R
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
with(X, {
  plot(x, y, asp=1, cex=3/4, col="#00000040", main="Joint Distribution")
  hist(x, freq=FALSE, breaks=25, main="Marginal Distribution of x")
  curve((3/4)*(1-x^2), add=TRUE, lwd=2)
  hist(y, freq=FALSE, breaks=25, main="Marginal Distribution of y")
})
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

These results (for larger values of `n`) were used to create the second and third figures.

Comment: Thank you, I think it makes sense now, and was confused because the histograms in the other posts were wrong compared to my found marginal distribution of X. I have to do two simulations, one based on the marginal densities for X and Y and the conditional distribution $Y|X$  and one based on the marginal densities for X and Y and the conditional distribution $X|Y$. I'm not sure witch  conditional distribution you have used here? It seems that you have used continuous distribution with CDF F can be generated as F 1(U) where
U is uniform on (0, 1). You used the conditional distribution $X|Y$?

Comment: As $F^{-1}(U)$ of caurse

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach for the requested graphical results:

- Start by simulating points in the rectangle with vertices $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ so that $X\sim\mathsf{UNIF}(0,1)$ and, independently,
  $Y\sim\mathsf{Beta}(2,1).$
- Then throw away points not in $A.$
- Then plot histograms of the remaining $X$'s and $Y$'s, which will
  be negatively correlated.

Simulation in R:

```
set.seed(1129)
y1 = rbeta(10^4, 2, 1)
x1 = runif(10^4)
A = (x1^2+y1^2 < 1)
x = x1[A]; y = y1[A]  # keep points in A

summary(x); length(x); sd(x)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
0.0001593 0.1693985 0.3445088 0.3733047 0.5529737 0.9886407 
[1] 6579              # number of X's
[1] 0.2428481         # SD of X's
summary(y);  length(y);  sd(y)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
0.01055 0.41670 0.61122 0.59068 0.77998 0.99884 
[1] 6579
[1] 0.2326322
cor(x,y)
[1] -0.3749655        # Negative correlation
```

[image]

Code for figure:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
 plot(x,y, pch=".")
 hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
 hist(y, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

*Note:* You will get better approximations for marginal means and
standard deviations, and for the correlation if you start with a million points. But then the scatterplot is to conjested
to read. So I used only $10\,000$ initial points, of which
$6579$ are in set $A.$

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach is logically circular and does not achieve the aim of being a check on the analysis.  A proper check would not rely on any aspect of the analysis.  It would be based on the most direct possible implementation of the original specification.

Comment: My purpose was to show the difference between the original, obviously independent marginals, and the correlated marginals when restricted to the first quadrant $A$ of the unit circle.